# What determines the header's height and width?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this theme: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/ If you "inspect element" on the green portion (the element is named `<header>`
) and look at the list of all of its properties you'll notice that it has pixel values for height and width that dynamically change as you re-size the window.

Where are these values coming from?

I.e. If I was going to float something on top of it to cover, how would I make sure it stayed the same height?

Here's the values I'm referring to when inspected on chrome:
[image: Image to demonstrate how to reproduce question symptoms]

Comment: I've highlighted every single element in the *green portion* and I cannot see any change in PX values on resize. Also that page might go down over few months and your question will be invaluable. Please do your homework, create a simplified demo of your code, Post the relevant code, ask. and you'll get relevant help.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan that's one of the basic bootstrap themes, so I figured it will be around for quite a while. I'm referring to the entire <header> element. I'll make that more clear in my question. This question is just 100% to help me understand the deeper level behind css, so I think it does have quite a bit of value to new learners. Also I have done extensive homework (days worth), have figured out how to do what I'm trying to do, but realized I didn't fully understand why I couldn't do it more simply

Comment: I can agree only to some point. But if your link goes down... what value will your question present to future readers? A possible Answer will also be *off* cause of missing code...

Comment: It's not my link, bootstrap is a twitter framework, which I think will stand the test of time. I understand it's less than ideal, but copying and pasting ALL of the of the css files and html files to jsfiddle seemed silly. I would reduce the files to only the important ones causing the effect, but that's the crux of my issue, I don't know what files/css/javascript is causing the effect. It's a bit of a catch-22 but I do think it offers valuable knowledge if you can help

Comment: Can you explain where have you seen properties dynamically change? I must be tired, but I've opened console and cannot see anything like that happen...

Comment: I edited the question and uploaded a picture, using "inspect element" in chrome. If you inspect element on header and then click the bottom right corner of the window and re-size it, the height and width will change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69494/discussion-between-acoustic77-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing magic. You're looking at the **computed Box Model styles** which are dynamic as you approach to window resize. If you take a look at `styles` for the `<header>` element you'll notice that it's a classic HTML5 `<header>` block element which has `auto` (*"100%"*) width by default (like all block-level elements). Resizing the window you'll get the currently computed Element Size.

```
|    this is some long content here    |  
|                [IMAGE]               |  -- responsive width since `width:auto;`
|             more nice text           |  -- height dictated by content
```

vs:

```
|  this is  |  
|   some    |
|   long    |
|  content  |  -- responsive width since `width:auto;`
|   here    |
|  [IMAGE]  |  
| more nice |  
|   text    |  -- height dictated by content
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into those block elements. How is the height determined though? Height of the header element doesn't seem to be a function of window height

Comment: @Acoustic77 if you remove TEXT or IMAGES from it's child elements you'll notice that it'll start to loose height. Simply cause it has less/no content. So logically the height is dictated by the amount of content. On window resize, the content wraps inside that element taking more height -> that's why on smaller sizes the height grows by every line-height the text/content wraps.